# How to deduce the following equilibrium equation?

Tags: equilibrium, statics, stress-strain

I have seen the following free-body diagram in an engineering paper, [*J. Compos. Constr.* **9**, 388 (2005)](http://doi.org/10.1061/(ASCE)1090-0268(2005)9:5(388)) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240504813_Confinement_Effectiveness_in_Rectangular_Concrete_Columns_with_Fiber_Reinforced_Polymer_Wraps)):

> [image]

As it is mentioned in the paper $f_j$ is the stress in the FRP layer (which acts as a cable here) with a thickness $t$ and $f_r$ is the radial stress, which is being applied from the concrete inside. The radius of the corner in which $f_r$ is acting is $R$.

Now, according to the paper, this system acts like a pulley. The question is how can we deduce that

$$t f_j = R f_r\text{?}$$

It is written in the paper that if we assume the system as a pulley the above static equilibrium will be obtained.

The above-mentioned formula is numbered as formula (2) in the second page of the paper.

Comment: The link to the paper is currently broken. Please add a *stable* link to the paper (that means a DOI link, even if it's behind a paywall) as well as a complete bibliographic reference. You don't get to drop the basic academic requirements (like providing full references) just because you're on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the paper. Since I had seen many posts of this kind (without referring to the original paper and the authors), so I didn't include the reference to the paper. In addition, I am attributing anyone else's results to myself, so I didn't drop any basic academic requirements.

Comment: Providing a full reference is a basic academic requirement, independently of whether you attribute those results to yourself or not. The fact that other questions get that wrong doesn't mean you should. (Instead, you should fix those questions, when it's clear how to do so, or prod their authors into providing full references when it isn't.)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty ok, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f_j$ being the stress of the FRP sheet wrapped around the corner, the associated force is $F_j\equiv tf_j$. The corner is subject to $F_j$ applied to the left and downwards, and we can write the resultant force as $\vec{F}_{j \text{ res}} = -F_j\hat{\imath} - F_j\hat{\jmath}$, so that
$$F_{j \text{ res}} = \sqrt{2}F_j = \sqrt{2}tf_j.$$
Now, the corner is circular and there's no friction which means $f_r$ is a radial force, $\vec{f}_r=f_r\hat{r}$. And the resultant of $f_r$ is the integral along the length $s$ of the corner:
$$ \vec{F}_{r \text{ res}} = \int \vec{f}_r ds = f_r\int\hat{r}ds = f_r\int_0^{\pi/2}\hat{r}Rd\theta = Rf_r\int
_0^{\pi/2}\cos{\theta}\,\hat{\imath}+\sin{\theta}\,\hat{\jmath} \;d\theta = Rf_r(\hat{\imath}+\hat{\jmath}).$$
Thus
$$ F_{r \text{ res}} = \sqrt{2}Rf_r.$$
The equilibrium condition demands that $F_{j \text{ res}} =  F_{r \text{ res}}$, which leads to their equation: $tf_j=Rf_r$.

<sub>The calculation of the magnitude of the forces can be avoided. For example, we can enforce equilibrium in the $\hat{\imath}$ or $\hat{\jmath}$ direction, arriving at $-tf_j+Rf_r=0 \Longrightarrow tf_j=Rf_r$ as well.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain more about the resultant of $fr$. I don't understand that part. For example, how $\int \vec{f}_r ds = f_r\int\hat{r}ds$ or even why you are taking the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$? Shouldn't it be from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: Another point is that in the paper it is written that the above equilibrium equation is found from the static of forces either in the horizontal direction or in the vertical direction.  Therefore, it is not obtained from the resultant of the forces in the diagonal direction.

Comment: @M.Rock, the $2\pi$ was a typo, it's corrected now. In the corner, though, you do have a force with both vertical and horizontal components, there's no way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it is clear. But why the writer has written that the equilibrium equation is obtained either by the equilibrium of forces in the horizontal or in the vertical directions?

Comment: @M.Rock, they are referring to the fact that any force in 2D can be decomposed in horizontal and vertical components. The calculation of the resultant magnitude can be avoided, BTW, check the new edit.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. Thanks for your complete answer. It is a great start with the Physic StackExchange. :-)

Comment: @stafusa Do you remember what the original paper was in the OP? Can you reconstruct the full reference?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I found it and updated the OP.